# DirectionalViewPager with 30 buttons in every page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to use [DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) for displaying 30 buttons in every page. Normally this viewpager is working perfectly. But, if I try this pager after adding buttons then the touch is not sensible or smoother. I observe lag and irregular touch sense when there are some clickable items on the fragment.

When I try dragging the pages by dragging using non-clickable items, then its working perfectly.

Can any one assist me to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred due to the Child buttons in the gridview. Because If we override onTouch method for the Button then the X and Y points are given with respect to that particular button only. So if you are passing these values to the parent then you should change the values according to the parent or else you can directly pass the Button's X,Y points which will improve the Touch sensitivity more.

Comment: I used the same kind of code below. btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if(v instanceof CustomImageButton && event.getPointerCount() == 2)
      v.performClick();
     event.setLocation(v.getLeft(), v.getTop());
     return swipeDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
     
    }
    
   });